# How do I use request-specific information in attribute-based MVC authorization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an app that uses an ApplicationFilter to secure some controller actions, like this:

```
[MustLogInOrPay]
public virtual ActionResult DownloadImage( int imageId ) {
...
}
```

So, MustLogInOrPay extends ActionFilterAttribute, and it redirects them, if necessary, to a page where the user either logs in or pays and then continues on to where they were going. Seems to work fine.

I want to make the authorization smarter and allow a user who has paid to download the same image an unlimited number of times during their session, to mitigate the chances of them being frustrated if the initial download fails.

Unfortunately the code making the decisions is in MustLogInOrPay, and that doesn't have the imageId available to it. So the only two ways forward that I know of are 1) Have MustLogInOrPay's code dig into the raw request to find the imageId, which sounds yucky, or 2) Begin DownloadImage with the code that is currently inside MustLoginOrPay, essentially throwing the Attribute-based mechanism in the garbage. Is there a better way? What is the best practice for using request-specific information inside a global authorization filter?

Comment: The best approach for this for me is adding a field to  AspNetUsers like "paid" and then retrieve and check it when user tries to download.

Comment: @Hadee We store no user data. There is no such thing is an account. The most we store is transient data for the session. The system does not implement a membership provider.

Comment: But you have "MustLogInOrPay" which means you have "login"!!!. Anyway, you also could use  TempData[""].

Comment: @Hadee I understand that's confusing. The log in is SSO with an external system. And that does not apply to the Pay scenario I am talking about. I do not understand how temp data helps.

Comment: So you are right. TemData doesn't help. Another way is using "SystemWebHttpContext.Current.Session".

Comment: @Hadee Obviously session state can be used to store data but it doesn't address the problem. I already have all of the previously-paid-for images stored in session - that doesn't help the block of code in the attribute know what image the current request is asking for. The only way session could be the answer is if you double the number of web methods and have a unrestricted method first store the imageId in session and then redirect to the DownloadImage action, but that seems very undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding AuthorizeCore Method, you should have access to the imageId inside the authorization filter as follows:

```
public class MustLogInOrPay : AuthorizeAttribute  
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        string imageId= httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["imageId"].ToString();
    }
}
```